# Report x,y coordinates after mouseup button event happens

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

This jsfiddle allows one to drag around a square. It uses angularjs.

http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/35z4J/

I would like the console to report the x,y coordinates after the mouse button is lifted. Currently, the console only sends the `STOPPING` message. Below is the relevant controller code.

```
.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) { 
    $scope.dragOptions = {
        start: function(e) {
          console.log("STARTING");
        },
        drag: function(e) {
          console.log("DRAGGING");
        },
        stop: function(e) {
          console.log("STOPPING");
        },
        container: 'container'
    }
```

How can the code be modified such that the console report the x,y coordinates after the mouse button is lifted?

EDIT: The answer has been provided for the x,y coordinates of the mouse pointer. Suppose I want to get the x,y coordinates of the centre of the square. How can that be done?

Comment: Who's coordinates? Pointer or the item you're dragging ?

Comment: @toby: very interesting question. For mouse pointer, the answer is already provided. Is it possible to get the coordinates of the item being dragged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MouseEvent.clientX`    // Get the horizontal coordinate

`MouseEvent.clientX`     // Get the vertical coordinate

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX)

**[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/35z4J/114/)**

Comment: Thanks! Particularly for the demo.

Comment: I made some new request to the question. Would you be able to help? Thanks a lot.
EDIT: The answer has been provided for the x,y coordinates of the mouse pointer. Suppose I want to get the x,y coordinates of the centre of the square. How can that be done?

Comment: @user768421 check this updated fiddle you will get coordinates from center of div  http://jsfiddle.net/35z4J/115/

Comment: Thanks. It's working fine. But I have a question on your code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942707/where-does-this-mouseevent-property-come-from

Answer (score 2):

Try `console.log("X: %o. Y: %o", e.x, e.y)`.

Comment: For the future: You can log whole objects, such that you can see their properties. `console.log(e);` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `console.log(e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY);` to the line following `console.log("STOPPING");` will do what you're wanting. The mouse position is contained within the MouseEvent `e`.

Answer (score 1):

For the rectangle you can use `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`.

So you would have something like: `console.log(e.target.getBoundingClientRect());`

Documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)