# Where does this MouseEvent property come from?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, mouseevent

I have this jsfiddle which reports the x,y coordinates of a white square that is being moved around by the mouse when the mouse button is released.

http://jsfiddle.net/35z4J/115/

This part of the code helps to report the x,y coordinates of the centre of the square.

```
stop: function(e) {
  console.log("STOPPING");
    var divheight= e.path[0].offsetHeight;
    var divWidth= e.path[0].offsetWidth;
    console.log(e.clientX+divWidth/2)
     console.log(e.clientY+divheight/2)

},
```

The 2 lines of code from the above that puzzles me are;

```
var divheight= e.path[0].offsetHeight;
var divWidth= e.path[0].offsetWidth;
```

I looked at the MouseEvent documentation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent
I cannot find anything about `path.offsetHeight` and `path.OffsetWidth`. What are those? Where can I find the relevant documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `path` is a property of the event object which contains all the ancestors in tree order.

See [Dispatching events](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dispatching-events)

> If event’s target attribute value is participating in a tree, let
>   event path be a static ordered list of all its ancestors in tree
>   order, and let event path be the empty list otherwise.

So `e.path[0]` will refer to the element from where the event was originated. Then the [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) has the [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) property

Comment: Another question ... do I need some sort of debugger to see what are on path property of the event object?

Comment: We are using `path[0]` because we want to read the properties of the `shape` element

Comment: @user768421 http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/su69L5ps/1/ - you can use console logging... see the console to inspect the values

Comment: How do I know when to use `path[0]` or `path[1]`? Any documentation on that? Or do I use a debugger to see which index to use? Sorry, I am not familiar to web application development.

Comment: @user768421 instead of `e.path[0]` you can also use `e.target`

Comment: @arun Is `event.path` widely supported? It worries me to use it when I don't see it mentioned anywhere in the [MouseEvent Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent).